# Difference between split(' ') and split ( /( )/ )

Tags: javascript, regex, split

I can't understand why is `split(/(?:_| )+/)`. The '?' means "if followed" but why I need to use it in this case?
I thought that split(' ') and split(/( )/) are "split on a white space" but in the second case it returns an array with empty elements between words. The split method doesn't return the separator.

```js
function spinalCase(str)
  {     
  // Replace low-upper case to low-space-uppercase     
  str = str.replace(/([a-z])([A-Z])/g, "$1 $2");   
    
  // Split on whitespace and underscores and join with dash    
  return str
        .toLowerCase()
        .split(/(?:_| )+/)
        .join("-");
  }
    
// test here 
 console.log( spinalCase("This Is Spinal Tap") );
```

Comment: Why would you "need" to use it at all? Who says you need to use it? You use `(?:...)` if you want a non-matching group (e.g. `(?:moo){3}` would match `moomoomoo`) but that makes no sense here based on the code comment, because `.split(/[ _]+/)` would already do exactly what that text says you want to do. It kind of looks like someone didn't quite understand regex well enough to understand character classes, but did know about groups and `|` as "or" character, and so wrote something that technically works, but just doesn't make a lot of sense to use.

Comment: I know that code works.  Why if i write `.split(/(_| )/)` it return empty spaces too? I mean split doesn't return the separator in  `.split(/(_| )/)` empty space and underscore are the separators so why it returns the empty space in the array? It's a FreeCodeCamp solution but I really don't understand why ti return the separator if I use the code above.

Comment: because now you've written a capture group. Capture groups are preserved. Because you want their result captured. That's what they're for. To stop that from happening, you use `?:` inside the parentheses to turn it into a _non-capture group_ so they don't end up part of the result. However, since you're splitting on individual characters (underscore or space) rather than _sequences_ of characters (such as "a space followed by an underscore"), there is no reason to use parentheses at all. Use a character class: `[ _]+` (or `[_ ]+`) does the same as `(?:_| )+` while much easier to read.

Comment: Thank you. I thought that the `split()` method never returns its separator in any case.